# In ASP.NET Core Blazor server app navigation is working for some link but not for other, just showing ""Sorry, there's nothing at this address.""

Tags: asp.net-blazor

### AddProduct.razor

@page "/AddProduct"

#### Add Product

@code {

}

### NavMenu.razor

```
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="AddProduct">
            <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Add Product
        </NavLink>
    </li>
```

Any help! I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: add "/" to your url like this: <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/AddProduct">, local address should start with "/".